# just wrap element that have not been wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have wrapped the **img** element with the jquery wrap function.

```
$('.post').each(function(){
   $(this).find('img').wrap('<span/>');
};
```

HTML

```
<div id ='post1' class='post'>
   aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
   **<span>**<img/>**</span>**
   aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
</div>
```

this does not work after load more page by infinite scroll. so I have to add the following script

```
$(document).on('load resize', function){

   $('.post').each(function(){
      $(this).find('img').wrap('<span/>');

   });
});
```

but the **span** will be added each load the next page, so if it is assumed, the post image on the first page has been wrapped **span** with jquery wrap, then when loading the second page, the post image will be wrapped with a span of "*on load function*" but also repeats to wrap the image on the first page, and so on

```
<div id ='post1' class='post'>
   bbbbbb bbbbbb
   <span><span><span><img/><span><span></span>
   bbbbbb bbbbbb
</div>

Load page 2...

<div id ='post2' class='post'>
   aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
   <span><span><img/><span></span>
   aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
</div>

load page 3...

<div id ='post3' class='post'>
   cccccc cccccc
   <span><img/><span>
   cccccc cccccc
</div>
```

i just want to wrap the img element that has not been wrapped by 'span' after load more page. What should I do?

Comment: You can either keep track of "spanless" images, or check the parent of `$(this)` before wrapping.

Comment: @Teemu , I think I've found the solution. thank you for your reply bro..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the post to tell the script it has already been handled:

```
$(document).on('load resize', function){
    $('.post:not(.wrapped)').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("wrapped").find('img').wrap('<span/>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried it. and this works perfectly. thank you for helping me